# same virt and res for a process

Tags: linux, multithreading, process

I have a process running with so many threads.
When I do top -H -p with that process ID, the VIRT and RES in the output is always the same for all the threads during the process run.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the same values because threads in Linux share the same address space (page tables, to be more precise).

Linux threads are created via `clone` system call using `CLONE_VM` flag, which means that they share the same page tables (see `Understanding the Linux Kernel`, Chapter 3). On my machine, creating two threads with `libpthread` leads to the following calls:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7fbcc9aeaff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID ...
[...]
clone(child_stack=0x7fbcc92e9ff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID ...
```

One possible question is: how does it work with the stack then, which is known to be private to each thread? The stack is `malloc`ed by the parent and set via `child_stack` parameter. And since both threads share the same page tables, no matter what they do on the stack, `VIRT` and `RES` will always be the same.